# Popup and jquery (open and action after close)

Tags: jquery, popup

I have a small problem with my code.  I open a popup with `jquery`, which works fine.  This popup is called `"popUp"` (for example).

I would ensure that if the popup is closed within 10 seconds for example displayed on the site from which the popup is open:

`$("#protecAnimaux").val('fenêtre fermée avant 10 secondes...');`

and if the popup remains open at least 10 seconds so I could run another code but for example can be displayed:

```
$("#protecAnimaux").val('tout est ok !!');
```

I use this code for open the popup

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttons', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).data("href");
    var windowName = "popUp";//$(this).attr("name");
    var windowSize = windowSizeArray[$(this).attr("rel")];
    window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
    windowvote = window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
});
```

Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It could work like this: When you click the button and you open your window - you set a timestamp ( `lastTime` in the example code). Next you start an interval (or timeout function) and test:

- If the time passed since opening fulfill your requirements by comparing the difference of `lastTime` with `cTime`, where cTime is current Time in seconds with your `delayMinTime`.
- The status of the window by using the window instance, in your case `windowvote`.

This brings up the following code example. to test it, click [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGaGwM?editors=1111).

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttons', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).data("href");
    var windowName = "popUp";//$(this).attr("name");
    var windowSize = windowSizeArray[$(this).attr("rel")];
    var delayMinTime = 10; //  time for warning in seconds
    var closeTime = 60; //  time for warning in seconds
    var lastTime = new Date();
    var windowvote = window.open(url, windowName,windowSize);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        var cTime = Math.floor((new Date() - lastTime)/1000);
        if ( cTime < delayMinTime  && windowvote.closed !== false) {
            // window closed, warning message and kill timer
            $("#protecAnimaux").val('fenêtre fermée avant 10 secondes...');
            clearInterval(timer);
        } else if ( cTime > delayMinTime) {
            // status is fine...
            $("#protecAnimaux").val('tout est ok !!');
            if(Math.floor(cTime >  closeTime ) {
                // in case you want to close 
                // (that was the first request)
                windowvote.close();
                clearInterval(timer);
                // in case you want to reload or load
                // a new url do...
                windowvote.location.href = 'yournewurl'; 
            }
        }      
    },100);
});
```

Comment: Hello  
Nice thank you it's work's :)
but I need also when user launch the popup, this popup is reload each 60 seconds (for example) with a link obtain in query sql. Many thanks you :)

Comment: @Fabien14 well, there is nothing like this in your question and i am not sure what exactly you want - update your question ask a new one, or try to modify the given answer, i have updated the example to demonstrate a load of a new url instead of closing. For anything further be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I try to ensure that when the user launches the popup, this one displays a website that I get the url via a SQL query and after 15 seconds ( example) the popup will reload with another URL that just the application. In fact I also appear on the site from the popup or left the site that is currently being displayed with $ ( "# outstanding") val (url). and every 15 seconds it changes and reload the URL popup with the new url :) I created a new topic but I do not think I was clear :)

[Reload popup with query sql Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378202/reload-popup-with-query-sql-jquery)

Comment: Please post on Stack Overflow in English only. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recapitulate because I was not very clear :)
I launch a popup with this code:

I wish that the content of the popup is loaded with a URL that we have a php file (animaux.php), that loading is done to open the popup.
I display on the parent URL is currently in the popup.

My question is how to reload (And not close) the popup every X seconds with URL in a PHP file which returns me the new URL.