# Reload popup with query sql Jquery

Tags: jquery, popup

I need help for ma animals website

I need launch a popup (it's ok)

```
<input type='submit' rel="0" data-target="_blank"  class='refresha' id='refresha' value=' Lancer protec animaux' />
```

and Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.refresha', function(e) {
    var url = //How take url in a php file with a query ?
    var windowName = $( this ).data( 'id' );
    var windowSize = windowSizeArray[$(this).attr("rel")];
    windowvote = window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
    windowvote.moveTo(600, 0);  
    var timer = setInterval(function() {   
        if(windowvote.closed) {                             
            $("#protecAnimaux").val('fenêtre fermée avant 10 secondes...');
            clearInterval(timer);  
        }else{
            // After timer, i need popup is reload with a new link obtain by the php file with the query sql.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "link.php",
                data: url,
                success: function(){    
                    windowvote.reload();   
                }
            });

            $("#protecAnimaux").val('fiche animaux test!!');
            clearInterval(timer);
        }  
    }, 3000); 
});
```

After timer, i need popup is reload with a new link obtain by the php file with the query sql.

Many thanks for your Help.

Comment: I do not understand your question, please elaborate on "i need popup is reload with a new link obtain by the php file with the query sql"

Comment: Is the url always the same or does the url contains any dynamic parameter?  if not, see my modified answer from the first question. All you need to do ist loading the url all 60 seconds (or whatever you define) with windowvote.location.href = yoururl

Comment: I recapitulate because I was not very clear :) I launch a popup with this code: I wish that the content of the popup is loaded with a URL that we have a php file (animaux.php), that loading is done to open the popup. I display on the parent URL is currently in the popup.

My question is how to reload (And not close) the popup every X seconds with URL in a PHP file which returns me the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer on question which is hidden in the code:

```
var url = //How take url in a php file with a query ?
```

You can store url in you input tag:

```
<input type='submit' data-url=<?=$urlFromPhp?> rel="0" data-target="_blank"  class='refresha' id='refresha' value=' Lancer protec animaux'/>
```

And you can get it in jQuery this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.refresha', function(e) {
  var url = $(this).data('url');
  ...
```